# Express.JS AND Ember.JS working together?

Tags: express, ember.js

I usually work with **Express.JS** (and **PUG** for my views).

Now I've stumbled upon **Ember.JS** and am starting to like it.

Is there a good way of *connecting* them?

I mean you need to *mix* them somehow?

Thanks, folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rather broad question and can (most likely) lead to opinionated answers, but I'll try to remain on the track.

These tools serve different purpose, but I see 3 cases where they can be used together. There might be other cases, but your mileage may vary.

### Express is used to serve Ember assets through views

This is the case where you use Express as a backend server. If you need to serve the Ember application using some server logic, this is one way to go.
For example, you may want to have the authentication part done by Express (e.g. not by Ember), let's say to restrict access to some parts of the Express application: assets, pages, or your Ember application.

and you will end up [rendering your dynamic templates](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) with a `script` tag sourcing to your static Ember application.

Any other combination of language/server works here, choosing Express is only a matter of taste.

### Your Ember application consumes an API

Again, I assume you write your API using JavaScript, and you want to serve it using Express. This is also a matter of personal taste.

### You want to use server-side rendering for your Ember application

This is the only case where you will use Express, wether you want it or not.

Server-side rendering for Ember application is done with [`fastboot`](http://ember-fastboot.com/), which is used with [`ember-cli-fastboot`](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/ember-cli-fastboot), which has a `dependency` (**not** a `devDependency`) to Express (see the [ember-cli-fastboot package.json](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/ember-cli-fastboot/blob/master/package.json) file).

If you don't know about Fastboot, I suggest you watch [this introduction video](https://vimeo.com/157688134).

---

### Conclusion

You don't need to mix these tools, but there are various ways of using Ember in conjunction with Express.
The only case where you **have** to use Express is if you use ember-cli-fastboot.

Comment: thank you, but could you explain the first case again, and in more depth, please ??

Comment: @Timo I added a quick example to the first case, but since this is rather broad, there are better examples somewhere in the wild :-)

Answer (score 3):

The most appropriate way of connecting them is to use Express.js purely as an API server, delivering json data to your Ember.js application.

Ember is responsible for all the routing, templates, etc.

The slight challenge comes when you need to initially get Express to server the Ember app when the user first hits your website.
The way I would approach this is to have all the api end-points preceded with `api` in the url, e.g.

```
app.get('/api/posts', function(req, res) {
  ...
});

app.get('/api/posts/:id', function(req, res) {
  ...
});

app.post('/api/posts', function(req, res) {
  ...
});
```

And then finally, for all other routes return the Ember app

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(<..location of Ember index.js>)
});
```

Express would be purely an API server, so you wouldn't need your Pug templates.
There's a really good tutorial here [ProgramWithErik](http://www.programwitherik.com/setup-your-ember-project-with-node/) that goes into more specific detail of the Express set-up.